# the requested range does not exist in the sheet

Tags: office-365, excel-online

When i'm trying to open an excel File in Excel Online, i get this error!
"the requested range does not exist in the sheet"

I can't open the file.

How i can fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Does the sheet open without error in the desktop version of Excel?  If so I can only assume that the Excel sheet is trying to do something that is not supported in Excel Online.  Excel Online does not have all the same functionality that the desktop version has.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem recently when using teams and found a few things that can "fix" it.

First of if your data is pasted from one sheet to another then make sure that the formatting doesn't go all the way to the bottom as the web version of Excel doesn't go as high as the 1million + rows.

Second thing to check if you have hidden rows to the bottom of the
sheet don't use Freeze panels to stop the scrolling as this also can break it.

If your data does stretch down over the limited rows then try to break up your data as the line limit will cause this error.